# What type of structure for saving chat history in Redis

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I am writing chat program and I want to do history of chats so I need to store some values. First is post data like:

```
 {chat_post_id,text,room_name}
```

where chat_postid will be incremented automaticly and text and roon_name i get from chat. After collecting some posts I need to connect them in some way with user who wrote them, so I need something like this:

```
 Thomas
   chat_postid_1,text,room_name
   chat_postid_2,text,room_name
   chat_postid_3,text,room_name
 Kris
   chat_postid_1,text,room_name
   chat_postid_2,text,room_name
   chat_postid_3,text,room_name
```

I am not sure if its is possible using redis - i am new to this nosql database concept. 
I think i shoud use hashes in some way but have no idea how.

Comment: i found solution by myself. To achieve it i need to :

 db.incr('messagesId',function(err,id){
   db.hmset('message:'+id,'room',room,'text',text,redis.print)
  db.lpush(nickname,'message:'+id)

 })

Now i can lrange nickname 0 -1 to get all messages from that specific nickname and then just loop through them and get all values using hgetall.

Comment: unfortunatelly i cant add repys to my own question

Comment: You can edit the question ;) And a very nice answer !!!

Comment: Don't forget to set expiry :)